# SQL Server select within select invalid column name

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server. I have the following query:

```
select 
    convert(varchar(10), MAX(closedate), 101) 
from 
    (select PSer.Signin_Date as closedate 
     from PSer 
     where ID = '12')
```

Note that the content within my from is more complicated than the simplified version I have.

I get a message saying

> Invalid column name closedate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're giving your subquery an alias.

```
from ( select PSer.Signin_Date as closedate from PSer where ID = '12') AS SOMENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
select convert(varchar(10),MAX(t1.closedate),101) 
from ( select PSer.Signin_Date as closedate from PSer where ID = '12') as t1
```

enjoy.